# How to write the code of equations with braces on the left in miktex

Tags: cases

Here is the code i write in the mathematics stack exchange(website). At first, i think the code in the  mathematics exchange and MikTeX (I use WinEdt as the front-end) are the same. However, their results are a little bit different.

The first figure is the result in the mathematics exchange,and this is exactly what i wanted. However, the second figure is the result from LaTeX.

Does anyone know how to modify the code to let the LaTeX result be correct?

```
\documentclass{article}
 \begin{document}

     $$\begin{cases}
        \eta \alpha_0 p_0g_{r,k} \\[2ex]
        \eta \alpha_0 p_0g_{r,k}+
     \end{cases}$$

 \end{document}
```

[image]

(mathematics stack exchange)

[image]

(LaTeX)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. WinEdt is a front-end to a TeX distribution; it is *not* the program that does the actual typesetting. Please tell us which TeX distribution you employ -- MiKTeX, TeXLive, or something else?

Comment: @Mico its MiKTeX

Comment: (i) in `latex` don't use `$$ ...$$` for displayed math environment,  correct is for example `\[ ...  \]`; (ii) in your code is missing package  `˙amsmath` . try to add `\usepackage{amsmath}` into preamble.

Comment: @Zarko   but my result is still the same

Comment: no, than you doing something else from what you show to us. see my answer

Comment: @ShineSun - Please familiarize yourself with the behavioral guidelines of this site. One of them is that one should wait several hours, and maybe even a day or more, before "accepting"/checkmarking an answer. The reason why one shouldn't immediately 'accept' a promising-looking answer is that doing so strongly discourages others from providing additional, and potentially even better answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- math environment delimetrs `$$` are used in tex, for lateh is defined `\[` ... `\]`.
- environment `cases` is defined in the `amsmath` package. it missing in your mwe (minimal working example
- normaly `cases` has two columns separated with ampersands
- code copied from my "WinEdt" editor is

  ```
  \documentclass{article}
  \usepackage{amsmath}
   \begin{document}
  \[
   \begin{cases}
          \eta \alpha_0 p_0g_{r,k}   &      \\[2ex]
          \eta \alpha_0 p_0g_{r,k}+  &
   \end{cases}
  \]
   \end{document}
  ```

which after compilation gives:

[image]

Comment: yes!! it works!! i  think maybe i write like this \[\begin{cases}.....\end{cases}\]

Comment: @ShineSun, in this case you got error in compilation ...

Comment: Your answer does *not* explain why the OP's code runs without crashing (but indeed producing some unexpected and undesired output) if the `amsmath` package is not loaded.

Comment: @mico, no. i just show, how op codes should be in latex. this deficiency your answer hasn't. +1 for it :-)

Answer (score 1):

On math.stackexchange.com, what's being run isn't actually LaTeX but mathjax. The input syntax is very similar, but that doesn't mean that the underlyings programs are the same.

A little known fact is that the LaTeX kernel provides a command (not *environment*) called `\cases`. If the `amsmath` is *not* loaded -- as is the case in your sample code -- it's the `\cases` command that is executed when you provide `\begin{cases} ... \end{cases}` code. (Essentially, `\begin{cases}` becomes `\cases`, and `\end{cases}` is ignored and doesn't throw an error.)

What you really should do in your LaTeX code is add the instruction

```
\usepackage{amsmath}
```

`\usepackage{mathtools}` works too. That's because `mathtools` loads the `amsmath` package automatically. (The `mathtools` package also provides the closely-related environments `cases*`, `dcases`, and `dcases*`.)

I believe that even most LaTeX experts are quite unaware of the existence of the `\cases` macro, let alone what it does. The `\cases` macro is honestly not very useful even under the best of circumstances. I assume that's why it got essentially overwritten (bulldozed?!) when the `amsmath` package and its `cases` environment were introduced.

Finally, it's worth noting that mathjax automatically emulates the most important features of the `amsmath` package. That's why you're getting the expected result on mathjax even though it's not necessary to load the `amsmath` package explicitly.

---

An MWE (minimum working example). Note the little gap after `\eta` in the `cases` version. That's because `\begin{cases}` is translated into `\cases`, and `\cases` takes one argument. Note also that the remaining material after `\eta` is shifted down a bit relative to `\eta`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
% renamed version of LaTeX-kernel 'cases' macro:
\def\xcases#1{\left\{\,\vcenter{\normalbaselines\m@th
    \ialign{$##\hfil$&\quad{##}\hfil\crcr#1\crcr}}\right.}
\makeatother

%\usepackage{amsmath} % big effect if this instruction is commented out!

\begin{document}
\[
\begin{cases} 
        \eta \alpha_0 p_0g_{r,k} \\
        \eta \alpha_0 p_0g_{r,k}
\end{cases}
\]

\[
\xcases{\eta \alpha_0 p_0g_{r,k}\\
        \eta \alpha_0 p_0g_{r,k}}
\]

\[ % trying to make [x]cases useful:
\xcases{\begin{array}{l}
        \eta \alpha_0 p_0g_{r,k}\\
        \eta \alpha_0 p_0g_{r,k}
        \end{array}}
\]
\end{document}
```